# Upload an image with reactjs and mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, forms, mongoose

I'm trying to make an image uploader, thanks to a form, in reactjs.
I've created an api in mongodb (thanks to express, mongoose, etc.), and i'm trying to use it in order to upload an image.

Actually, i would like to send an image file to the cloud (with Cloudinary), and get the url.

**That is my form and methods** :

```
class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            uploading: false,
            image: [],
            apiKey: 'xxx'
        };
    }
    onChangeImage = e => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: Array.from(e.target.files)});
    };

   sendImage = files => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        files.forEach((file, i) => {
            formData.append(i, file)
        });
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/image-upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers : new Headers({
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'x-access-token' : this.state.apiKey
            }),
            body: formData
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(image => {
                this.setState({
                    uploading: false,
                    image
                });
                return true;
            });
        return false;
    };

handleSubmit = (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();
 const { image } = this.state;
 this.sendImage(image);
};

render() {
   return(

      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="formAdd">
      <input type='file' id="image" name="image" onChange={this.onChangeImage} />
      <button className="contact-form-btn">
         Send<i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      </form>
   )
}
```

**About my API Controller :**

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res) {
        cloudinary.config({
            cloud_name: 'xxxx',
            api_key: 'xxxxx',
            api_secret: 'xxxxx'
        });
        const path = Object.values(Object.values(req.body.files)[0])[0].path;
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(path)
            .then(image => res.json([image]));
    },
};
```

The error code that I get is 500 'TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object'. 
Indeed, it not found **Object.values(Object.values(req.body.files)[0])[0].path**.
What I've missed ? 
**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to upload an image. Using `async/await`.

```
async uploadImage(image) {

        const form = new FormData();

        form.append('file', image);
        form.append('upload_preset', 'g5ziunzg');

        const res = await Axios.post('YOUR_CLOUDINARY_URL', form)
        console.log(res)
        return res.data;
    }
```

This will return an object with the `secure_url` which you can store in your mongo database. I am assuming you have a backend-api for this task.

Inside your formSubmit function, you can first call this function and receive this `secure_url`.

**Note that I am using `axios` here. This example can easily be translated to work with `fetch`.**

Comment: Well done ! Thank you so much! I don't know why I was using my API for uploading on servers. Your piece of code works fine !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Object.value` since `req.body.files` is an array and you need to check its length before access. Try it:

```
const [file] = req.body.files

if (file) {
  // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reactivity! Resolved by requesting directly the Cloudinary API!